# Link one page to another one in onChange Function

Tags: reactjs

I want to redirect the user to another page when the onChange of the Switch component is triggered. The function works but it does not redirect to the other page.

```
function onChange(checked) {
  console.log(`switch to ${checked}`);

  {<Link to={`user/${checked.id}`}>{checked}</Link>}
 }

class List extends PureComponent {

  render() {   

    const columns = [
      {
        title: <Trans>OS</Trans>,
        dataIndex: 'avatar',
        key: 'avatar',
        width: 72,
        fixed: 'left',
        render: text => <Avatar style={{ marginLeft: 8 }} src={text} />,
      },

      {

       render: (e,text,record) => (< Switch  onChange={onChange(text,record)} 
        defaultChecked={e} />)
        },
       }

    ]
  }     
}
```

Comment: Hello @Oğuzhan Aydın. Please provide some code snippets and/or error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The react-router `<Link />` component is transpiled to an HTML anchor element like `<a href="" />`. And, you have to return it from the render function to achieve that.

However; it looks like you are trying to redirect the user to the given path on click. You have to use `<Redirect />` in this case.

Here is an example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false
  }

  render () {
    const { redirect } = this.state;

    if (redirect) {
      return <Redirect to=`/user/${userId}`/>;
    }

    return (
      <Switch onChange={() => this.setState({ redirect: true })} />
    )
}
```

I didn't test the code but I hope that it is enough to present the concept.

Comment: Thank you Hilmi Erdem Kerem , it works.

Comment: @OğuzhanAydın It is nothing. If you approve my answer, It will be much appreciated!